# How do I read one line from a 3X3 Matrix in c++?

Tags: c++, matrix

I have a 3X3 matrix with values.

1, 0, 0,

0, 1, 0,

0, 0, 1

I am only interested in the last line of this matrix (0,0,1).

So how do I read only the last line?

I am working in c++ and use opencv.

edit:

Sorry for the vague question.

So i have this code

```
double rotation[] = { 1, 0, 0,
                      0, 1, 0,
                      0, 0, 1 };
Mat rotation_matrix(3, 3, CV_64FC1, rotation);
```

I want to store the last line in a variable so that I can perform some calculations on them.

I know the code below works, but is there any better solution?

```
double m20 = rotation_matrix.at<double>(2, 0);
double m21 = rotation_matrix.at<double>(2, 1);
double m22 = rotation_matrix.at<double>(2, 2);
```

Comment: Read it from what? A text file?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "read"?

Comment: How is this matrix stored? A code example showing how you're trying to do this would help immensely.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do that.

Get a pointer to the last row that you can use like a 3-element array:

```
double* last_row = rotation_matrix.ptr<double>(2);
```

Create a new 1x3 Mat object sharing the last row with rotation_matrix:

```
Mat last_row = rotation_matrix.row(2);
```

Same as above, but the last row is copied instead of shared:

```
Mat last_row = rotation_matrix.row(2).clone();
```

Pick the one you like the most.